# How to convert and save files(os.walk)

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a question about how to save files after I convert them from psd to jpg using python. Since I want to check every file, I used os.walk function. Here is my code.
When I run this, I have this error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test02.psd'

The folder I want to save files in is in the same category as python file.
But the psd file is in the subfolder somewhere.

How can I get over this?

```
from PIL import Image
import os


for path, dir, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.psd'):
            print('The {} is being converted to jpg...'.format(file))
            i  = Image.open(file)
            fn, fext = os.path.splitext(file)
            try:
                i.save('jpgs/{}.jpg'.format(fn)) # I created a folder named 'jpgs' already.
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: @Aran-Fey close, but not exactly the same. Your suggestion is about `os.listdir`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem is the same, `listdir` or not. I can rewrite it to be our canonical dupe for `listdir` _and_ `os.walk` if you'd prefer.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, you'll have to find a better duplicate. `os.listdir` returns the file _names_, `os.walk` returns a triplet root+list of files+list of dirs for each dir. Not as easy to grasp. That plus the fact that user used current directory and hoped it would solve it magically.

Comment: a canonical about 2 different functions? that's a bit of a stretch. I don't like duplicates & users which answer duplicates knowing that the dupe exists just for rep. If I find a good one, I'll close.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725117/python-existing-file-not-found-ioerror-errno-2-with-openpyxl) good enough?

Comment: @Aran-Fey absolutely not :) the title of this one is better IMHO (for my defence :))

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` walks recursively and in the lower directories, and loads the current dir of the file(s) in `path`. `file` is just the file *name*.

What would work with `os.listdir` (using current directory) or in the current directory (when `path` is `.`) doesn't work with `os.walk`. You have to prepend the root dir

```
i  = Image.open(os.path.join(path,file))
```

Comment: Thank you all guys for help and discussion. ^^*