# Can`t use the files inside my subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, logic, python-import

I`m creating a program that can read certain data from some txt files, the problem comes when I try to use the files inside subdirectories (the subdirectories are inside the main directory of the program. I'm using a for the option to find all the files and then create a new file with the info that I found. The main problem is that I can't read those files.

I tried using a for a function that creates a list of directories, files and roots, this works fine, but in the moment of running the file it says "it cannot be found txt file". The if not condition is made so the program excludes all.DS_Store files. I think the problem could be the way I open the file but im not sure

```
       for root, directories, filenames in os.walk("Files_to_Insert"):

                   if not (filenames[-1] == ".DS_Store"):
                           lastFile = filenames[-1]
                            print lastFile

                             with open (lastFile, 'rt') as myfile:
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: txt
The mistake happens in the with open because it can`t find the file.
When I print I get all the txt files, but I can,t use them in the "with open"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: existing file not found (IOError: \[Errno 2\]) when using os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725117/python-existing-file-not-found-ioerror-errno-2-when-using-os-walk)

Comment: You have to give `open` the path to the file as well, not just the filename.

Comment: i could make that inside the  "with open" or i need to make a new one? im new in python and the os library

Comment: `with open (os.path.abspath(lastFile), 'rt') as myfile:` should do it.

Comment: i get the same mistake

Comment: What is `if not (filenames[-1] == ".DS_Store")` supposed to do?

Comment: its only an if to block "DS:Store" files that apple generates, with it i also get the last element of the tuple , the last element is the txt file

Comment: Currently it's only checking whether the last file in each directory is named ".DS_Store"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195236/discussion-between-oscar-contreras-and-tgikal).

Answer (score 0):

A typical `os.walk` I use goes like this:

```
import os

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.endswith(".DS_Store"):
            continue
        print(os.path.abspath(f))
        with open (os.path.abspath(f), 'rt') as myfile:
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by giving the path and the text file in separate strings:

```
 for root, directories, filenames in os.walk("Files_to_Insert"):



        if  not(filenames[-1] == ".DS_Store"):
            lastFile = filenames[-1]
            # print (lastFile)

            with open(str(root) + '/' + lastFile,'rt') as myfile:
```